# SQLite select statement to extract part of string

Tags: sqlite

This should be an easy one for someone with more SQLite experience than myself.
I need a select statement to get the name out of the following example string:

```
{"email":"12345678@facebook.com","user_key":"FACEBOOK:12345678","name":"John Smith"}
```

The output I need is John Smith.

The number of characters before the name is not always the same so a simple substr command won't work. It needs to be dynamic so it can locate where the name starts and then spit it out. I think ltrim or rtrim may help, but even after researching those commands, I don't understand them very well. Also, SQLite doesn't offer instr or position, which might have been helpful, too!

Edit: the schema for this table is as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (msg_id TEXT PRIMARY KEY, thread_id TEXT, action_id INTEGER, subject TEXT, text TEXT, sender TEXT, timestamp_ms INTEGER, timestamp_sent_ms INTEGER, attachments TEXT, shares TEXT, msg_type INTEGER, affected_users TEXT, coordinates TEXT, offline_threading_id TEXT, source TEXT, channel_source TEXT, is_non_authoritative INTEGER, pending_send_media_attachment STRING, handled_internally_time INTEGER, pending_shares STRING, pending_attachment_fbid STRING, client_tags TEXT, send_error STRING, send_error_message STRING, send_error_timestamp_ms INTEGER, publicity TEXT, tracking TEXT );
CREATE INDEX messages_offline_threading_id_index ON messages ( offline_threading_id );
CREATE INDEX messages_timestamp_index ON messages ( thread_id, timestamp_ms DESC );
CREATE INDEX messages_type_index ON messages ( thread_id, msg_type, timestamp_ms );
```

The string I have above that I'm working with is from the sender column.

Comment: This particular snippet looks to be a dictionary. What language are you using to query the SQLite database and what is the particular schema for the table?

Comment: I'm just using SQLite statements through shell commands. And I updated my question with the schema. Thanks!

Comment: So you want SQLite to have a built-in JSON parser???

Comment: I'm not familiar with that. I just need something like SELECT SUBSTR(sender, 'name":"', endofstring) FROM messages to output John Smith. Obviously, though, that's not how substr works so I don't know what other options I have.

Comment: Is John Smith the sender from the messages table?

Comment: Also, there seems to be some inconsistencies in the schema, notably there is use of a `string` data type and a field that is named `text` which is a data type itself. Is this a pre-existing database or something that is being created by you?

Comment: John Smith is located at the end of the string. Everything from {"email" to Smith"} in the example is located in the sender field in the messages table. I typed it up exactly (substituting numbers and names where appropriate, of course). And this is a pre-existing database. Specifically, it's the database for Facebook Messenger for Android. I'm trying to extract the sender's name for further use.

Comment: SQLite *does* have [instr](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#instr). Which version are you using?

Comment: Ah, I thought I had 3.7.16, but I ran SELECT sqlite_version() to verify and I have 3.7.6.3. I'm going to update it so I can use instr. If I may ask, since instr is still a bit confusing to me, how would I use it in my scenario? Something like instr(sender, 'name') but I'm confused at the documentation stating that it "returns the number of prior characters plus 1." What number is it referring to and can I get it to go the opposite way considering I need what's _after_ name?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the language you're using but most of them support user defined functions (http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) and you could do

```
select jsonGetName(columnWithJsonText) from messages where ...
```

It's like a callback to your programming language where you defined which C/Java/PHP function gets called when using jsonGetName() in sqlite.

In that function (in your language of choice) you decode the json string and return the name property.